# Mongoose query inside a forEach loop can't return or set value for sum variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to calculate sum of each price of product queried from the db, using findById.
Where the id is from array of objects that I iterate using forEach loop.

```
module.exports.checkoutOrder = (reqBody, buyerId, isAdmin)=>{

    let sum =0;
    reqBody.items.forEach(item=>{

         Product.findById(item.productId,(error, result)=>{

            //console.log(result.price);
            sum += result.price;

        })
    }) console.log(sum);
```

The problem is, is I can't seem to get or set any variable inside the findById block. Even if I put return on the sum variable, it's always the same result 0. I'm sure that my query is returning a data when I console.log result.price.

I know there are other ways to sum data, I just want to know first why it doesn't work this way?

Comment: @NiceBooks, how can I output the sum though? I just put it outside the loop

Comment: Kindly refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd argument of findById `(err,result)=>{}` is a callback, which by nature does not run immediately. `console.log(sum)` runs before all callbacks & hence prints 0.

You need to wait until all callbacks have run. A crude solution would be to wrap the `console.log(sum)` inside a `setTimeout` with a reasonable delay.

A better solution would be use use the `exec` method to create Promise objects  `Promise.all` method to wait for all promises to complete.

```js
let promiseList = await reqBody.items.map(async (item,i)=> 
  Product.findById(item.productId).exec() 
);

Promise.all(promiseList).then((productList)=> {
  let sum = productList.reduce((acc,product)=> acc + product.price, 0);
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Comment: Hello. I assumed this code is already formatted correctly and tried it but I got an error "await is only valid in async function"

Comment: I still get the same error "await is only valid in async function". I removed forEach completely and replaced it with your code. The error points the await before the reqBody

Comment: I checked the code with dummy numbers instead of mongoose queries & it works. Have you added the async keyword before the map callback and the exec() method call after findById ?

Comment: Yes, exact same code above. Is it okay to codeshare here, here is my current code
[https://codeshare.io/N3emD8]

Comment: It's better to add the new code to your original question as an edit, so that others can see it. I think you have to add async before the (reqBody, buyerId, isAdmin)=> since you are using await inside.

Comment: Wow. It worked now after I put the async before the (reqBody, buyerId, isAdmin)=>. What a relief. I'm going to study your code thoroughly. I don't want to code blindly. Thanks

Comment: is the exec method you used here the same exec that is mentioned here?[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec]

Comment: The exec is from Mongoose https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById. It's in the first example.